# Replacing NSTextField with NSScrollView to get a scrollbar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview, nsscrollview

My OS X app written in Objective-C needs to display a varying `NSString*` variable `theString` which can get quite large.

I use Xcode IB to build a nib file which displays `theString` in a `NSTextField*` object `panel` declared inside AppDelegate.h like this:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *panel;
```

Now I can set the contents of `panel` inside AppDelegate.m like this:

```
self.panel.stringValue = theString;
```

This all works fine. But I now want to give my text field a scrollbar. So in place of a "Text Field" I choose a "Text View" from the Object Library, and get its blue line to generate me a new declaration of `panel` which now looks like this:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSScrollView *panel;
```

This now no longer works:

```
self.panel.stringValue = theString;
```

raising the error: `(!) Property 'stringValue' not found on object of type 'NSScrollView*'`

How do I need to fixup this statement?

(Might I just say I find the extensive Apple documentation on the topic byzantine and opaque. Why am I being naive to expect a simple answer to this simple question, as it all seems to imply? I must be missing something obvious -- what is it?)

Comment: Use the `string`-property instead (change outlet type as `NSTextView`).

Comment: @astoria - I apologise, I totally overlooked your comment. You're dead right, and it's the answer I've since discovered. (And you need to change (weak) to (strong) too)

Answer (score 0):

What you got was a NSTextView wrapped inside a NSScrollView. The scrollView is the thing that makes the scrollbars you want. It basically holds a potentially much larger view inside its viewport and shows only  small part of it, that you can shift around with the scroll bars. You need to get (another) reference from your code to the NSTextView inside the scrollView. You can find the NSTextView in the hierarchy in IB and attach to that.

This is in the direction of what you want but I think not quite what you need. The textView is a far more advanced control than a simple textField and probably more than you need. You could instead use a custom view by taking a NSScrollView that comes with a default NSView wrapped inside. Then instead of the NSTextView place your NSTextField on the NSView. The issue with this is that then you need to add some code to auto-resize the NSTextField and NSView based on the content of the textField. Once you got that sorted the scrollView will automatically arrange for the scrollbars that you need.

Comment: Yes of course, you are right. I was in the mindset of rebuilding the control already in the project by ripping out the NSTextView and putting in an NSView. I agree it is cleaner and safer to delete the entire thing and start over with an NSScrollView with integral NSView. Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: "What you got was a NSTextView wrapped inside a NSScrollView" – yes, that's just what IB object library tells me upfront. But how am I meant to get at the underlying NSTextView to get/set its "string" property?

Comment: I've since found a 1-line solution, which I've tested and it works fine. But it's so quirky I can't believe it's the way Apple expects me to do it.

Comment: `self.panel.string = theString`, panel is connected to the textview.